# Spring стек или Java EE стек?

Tags: java-8, стек

Какой стек учить Spring стек или Java EE стек? Какой больше востребован?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ложное противопоставление. Spring построен на стандартах входящих в JavaEE. Не зная их, настоящего профессионализма не достичь.